# How to manipulate mapped item based on its key in react native

Tags: react-native

I am using `.map` to show my array items on the screen.
Array -> `[Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday]`

Below is my code:

```
<ScrollView
  horizontal={true}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  contentContainerStyle={styles.horizontalView}>
  {weekArray.map((item, key) => ((
        <Text key={key} style={styles.TextStyle} onPress={_press}>
          {" "}{item.day}{" | "}
        </Text>
      ))
  )}
</ScrollView>;
```

My output is in the following way:

`Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday| Thursday| Friday | Saturday | Sunday |`

I want to remove the last `|` which comes after Sunday. I am very new to learning map, so I am not able to figure how to do it. I know it has do something with keys, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You can make it conditional, like  `{ key === weekArray.length - 1 ? ' ' : ' | '  }`. Also remove the in the front

Comment: Is there a way to do it with loops, because I also have to implement other things, which I think I can do it with loops if I get to know how to use loop in my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply condition inside your loop like this

```
{" "}{item.day}{(weekArray.length - 1) == key ? '' : " | "}
```

Answer (score 2):

The second param to `map` is the `index` ... so you could check for the `lastItem` in this way...

```
{weekArray.map((item, key) => (
        <Text key={key} style={styles.TextStyle} onPress={_press}>
          {key === weekArray.length - 1 ? ` ${item.day}` : ` ${item.day} | `}
        </Text>
      ))}
```

**Using `if-cond` ...**

```
  const renderItem = (index, item) => {
    if (index === weekArray.length - 1) {
      return ` ${item.day}`;
    }
    return ` ${item.day} | `;
  };
```

...

```
  {weekArray.map((item, key) => (
    <Text key={key} style={styles.TextStyle} onPress={_press}>
      {renderItem(key, item)}
    </Text>
  ))}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with `if loop`. your answer works, but I am curios to know if we can use loops here

Comment: Yes (it's gonna take more lines of code) ... but there you go...

Answer (score 1):

You can use key parameter as it is index to check for last item in your array

```
{key == weekArray.length-1?` ${item.day}`:` ${item.day} | `}
```